# Spring @Transactional value param with SpEL (Spring expression language)

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions, spring-el

In one of my service classes I have some methods annotated as such :

```
@Transactional(value="foodb")
public Bar getMeSomething(){
}
```

I recently learned about @Value with the power of Spring EL to get some values stored in a properties file. 
such as

```
@Value("${my.db.name}")
```

which works like a charm.

Now I'm trying to do the same with

```
@Transactional(value="${my.db.name}")
```

with no success ...

I get the following exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '${my.db.name}' is defined: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier '${my.db.name}' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!
```

Is what I am trying to do even supported by Spring ?

What can I do to get the my.db.name value inside that @Transactional annotation

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, it's not supported.

Here's an excerpt from org.springframework.transaction.annotation.SpringTransactionAnnotationParser

```
public TransactionAttribute parseTransactionAnnotation(Transactional ann) {
    RuleBasedTransactionAttribute rbta = new RuleBasedTransactionAttribute();
    rbta.setPropagationBehavior(ann.propagation().value());
    rbta.setIsolationLevel(ann.isolation().value());
    rbta.setTimeout(ann.timeout());
    rbta.setReadOnly(ann.readOnly());
    rbta.setQualifier(ann.value()); // <<--- this is where the magic would be
    // if it was there, but it isn't
```

Comment: OK thanks. Nevermind anyway ... the value I was using inside the @Transaction annotation was the qualifier name of the transaction manager .. and not the name of the databse (which incidentally were the same ... ) :) Thank you